# How to update Android platform-tools in a headless linux?

Tags: android

We have some CI hosts without X-Window installed, i know how to update SDK with android update command, but how can i update platform-tools with this command?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the following commands:

```
$ android list sdk
$ android update sdk --no-ui --filter 1,platform-tools
```

The first command lists the available packages that are still to be installed (indexed by number), as for example:

```
Packages available for installation or update: 9
   1- Android SDK Tools, revision 19
   2- Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 11
   ...
```

According to that list you can issue the second command to install the packages that you want to install.

The `--filter` option limits the update to the packages that you want to install. You specify those packages in a comma-separated format. Also, you can filter them by the index number provided in the listing resulting from the first command.