# Android Studio could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+

Tags: android, android-studio

Running a project in Android Studio fails with this error: `could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+`

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Actually this is the answer that works for me: 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/18900369/1038702

Answer (score 195, accepted):

From Android Studio go to:
Tools >> Android >> SDK Manager

Select and install "Extras|Android Support Repository"

Comment: +1 and worth noting that this is not the same as "Android Support Library"... You will want the  "Android Support Repository"

Comment: I've spent 2 days trying to fix the error. I realise from the start I didn't download the `support repository`, just saw your post a moment ago, then downloading. Problem solved ! thanks

Comment: My support repository version 12 is installed, and I'm still getting this error.

Comment: Thanks! This also fixed a problem for me with PhoneGap where an `cordova build android` was throwing a similar error!

Comment: The name has changed to "Local Maven repository for Support Library" (v28)

Comment: Tools >> Android >> SDK Manager >> SDK Tools >> Android Support Repository for AndroidStudio 2.1

Comment: The UI has changed enough that these answers no longer work (Android Studio 3.+).  Sigh.

Answer (score 23):

For me it worked after changing the version from 7:27.+ to 7:+

Comment: wow ... great ... for me when add camera plugin this error occured then resolved when     compile "com.android.support:support-v4:27+" to
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"

Comment: It worked for me also.. I tried invalidating cache and adding maven to build.gradle but nothing worked. Now just changed version 7:30.+ to 7:+ worked... Thanks a lot Osama yaccoub

Answer (score 18):

In Project > app > build.gradle file replace the line

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'29.+'
```

with

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

and line

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.+'
```

with

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:+'
```

Then clean build

Comment: Never use glob matches in the version as it may break code due version updates

Answer (score 14):

Also as as said on [How to update Android platform-tools in a headless linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712812/how-to-update-android-platform-tools-in-a-headless-linux)

```
 android list sdk

 android update sdk --no-ui --filter extra
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is no longer working in 2020 (SDK 30): `Filter extra not supported`

Answer (score 11):

It is very simple.
Kindly update and replace the below code in build.gradle(Project :App Name).

```html
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for Gradle-based projects, although it doesn't help so much if you're running `aapt`, `javac` and `dx` manually without Gradle.

Answer (score 3):

After installing `Extras|Android Support Repository`, It does not work for me. Then I change **v7:1.6** to **v7:1.8** in the `app` `build.gradle` file.

`com.android.support:appcompat-v7:1.8.+!` and It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Open `SDK Manager.exe` in your Android Studio folder and install a matching API.

Answer (score 0):

I found all these answers incorrect for me. Instead in your android studio look below on the left. There will be some help for this.

For example, you will notice
`This support library should not use a different version (32) than the compilesdkVersion (23)`

Then you change the version of to 23 like this

> compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23'

Now, you will see a message
`A newer version of com.android.support-v4 than 23 is available 23.4.0`.

Thats how I knew that the correct version is `23.4.0`

Comment: That's a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you see this after you've just created a new project in Intellij then try to recreate it again with "Use AndroidX artifacts" checked

Answer (score 0):

To whom came here for same error but version 29, change your support library to version 28:

build.gradle(app):

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'
    ...
}
```

None of googled solutions worked for me. Then I saw [Android](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions) has only support library up to version 28. It is weird that I got this error in an out-of-box created Android Studio project.

I'm not sure which Android Studio version was, cause I upgraded Studio after got error. Now in Android Studio 3.6.3, new projects coming with 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to build and run this project.
I had to add google in both sections.

**build.gradle (project)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

**build.gradle(app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2" //25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.github.nkzawa.socketio.androidchat'
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ////noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.+'
    ////noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.+'
    implementation ('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }

    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: To build and run this project: https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-android-chat

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error but version 26.

Downloading the libraries through the SDK Manager is no longer supported. The support libraries are now available through Google's Maven repository.

**Solution:**

In **build.gradle (project)** inside both ***buildscript/repositories*** and ***allprojects/repositories*** add this:

```
maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
```

**Result:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

It worked for me.