# Installing Java 7 along with already installed Java 8 to be able to build Android application

Tags: java, android, linux, android-studio

I just moved to new Ubuntu and, thus, installed the last java version which is 8 (or 1.8). I also installed Android Studio 0.5.7. However, Dalvik doesn't support Java 8, does it? I want to keep the current java 8 installed because I'm going to use it in Java projects but I also have to install Java 7 to be able to use it in Android. What's the right way to do this?

**UPDATE:**

The errors:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+.
     Required by:
         MyApplication:app:unspecified
```

**#app/build.grandle**

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: You can use Java 8 to compile to Java 7 (or Java 6) bytecode.

Comment: Just tell AS to use your Java 8 install.

Comment: @Code-Guru, it did, but it seemed it didn't understand my accent. is there another way?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: @Code-Guru, updated. In "project structure" -> SDK location I have "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_05" which is the correct path to jdk8.

Comment: Are you still having problems? The error you posted has got nothing to do with Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

error

> Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+.

is answered in [Android Studio could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621941/android-studio-could-not-find-any-version-that-matches-com-android-supportappco)

i.e in SDK Manager install/update Extras / Android Support Repository to use this dependency.