# intellij new Android Gradle Project

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have the latest edition of Intellij.
After creating a blank Gradle Android Project I get the following error message when attempting to build the project:

> Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
> > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
> >     Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+.
> >          Required by:
> >              test6:app:unspecified

How can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621941/android-studio-could-not-find-any-version-that-matches-com-android-supportappco)

Comment: You're correct it was the  Android Support Repository I was missing.
Closing question.

Comment: Just realised that Android Studio is actually just a cut down version of IntelliJ for Android.  This makes more sense now!