# error when creating new project in android studio

Tags: android, gradle

I'm new to android studio. I've created a new project with android studio, when I want to run it I've got this error :

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+
 Searched in the following locations:
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21/appcompat-v7-21.pom
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21/appcompat-v7-21.jar
 Required by:
     myappname:app:unspecified
```

one thing that surprised me is that I opened this link:

https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support

but this link is incorrect!

what is the cause of this error?
I have android support library installed:

[image]

Comment: Can you edit in your build.gradle files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621941/android-studio-could-not-find-any-version-that-matches-com-android-supportappco

Comment: yes I can. but why?!

Answer (score 2):

Go to the SDK Manager and install "Extras|Android Support Repository"

Comment: You need Android Support **Repository**, not just Android Support _Library_.