# Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'-Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I have been trying to integrate facebook sharing into my app. But i keep getting the following error :

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v4:[22,23).
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            //jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
>            //jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/
>            //repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
>            //repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/
>            file:/Users/geraldgoh/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
>            file:/Users/geraldgoh/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
>            file:/Users/geraldgoh/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/
>        Required by:
>            Facebook:app:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.dothis.facebook"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),  'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
}
```

Android manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.dothis.facebook" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />


    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"    />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Can someone help me on how to solve this error. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have written the wrong dependency information for compiling.

It's SDK not SADK.

`compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0`

Comment: yea i have changed it but the error still shows up.@Animesh Jena

Comment: Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v4:[22,23).

Comment: try this..:-  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'

    and if still you are facing the same problem..you might go to your sdk manager and update it.gothrough this link:-http://stackoverflow.com/a/20830540/4531611

Comment: @marian:-welcome,happy coding.If you think my answer helped you any way,please upvote or vote it best answer,That would be great.