# Build Android HelloWorld fails: dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'

Tags: android

I want to build my first android hello world app, but got this error, any idea what is going on?

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
> > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
> >     Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:15.+.
> >          Versions that do not match:
> >              23.1.0
> >              23.0.1
> >              23.0.0
> >              22.2.1
> >              22.2.0
> >              + 10 more
> >          Searched in the following locations:
> >              https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
> >              https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
> >              file:/Users/kukodajanos/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
> >              file:/Users/kukodajanos/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
> >              file:/Users/kukodajanos/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
> >          Required by:
> >              HelloWorld:app:unspecified

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621941/android-studio-could-not-find-any-version-that-matches-com-android-supportappco check this

Answer (score 0):

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'. Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:15.+.
```

You are requesting a very old version of `appcompat-v7` (`15.+`), one that is not available on your development machine. You have several other versions (`23.1.0 23.0.1 23.0.0 22.2.1 22.2.0 + 10 more`). Use one of them.