# Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0

Tags: android

Today I updated a new SDK, then my project caused a problem blow. I've already downloaded Android Support Repository, but it still didn't work.
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/24.2.0/appcompat-v7-24.2.0.pom
>            file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/24.2.0/appcompat-v7-24.2.0.jar
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/24.2.0/appcompat-v7-24.2.0.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/24.2.0/appcompat-v7-24.2.0.jar
>            file:/C:/Users/Owner.KFW-39238/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/24.2.0/appcompat-v7-24.2.0.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/Owner.KFW-39238/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/24.2.0/appcompat-v7-24.2.0.jar
>            file:/C:/Users/Owner.KFW-39238/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/24.2.0/appcompat-v7-24.2.0.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/Owner.KFW-39238/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/24.2.0/appcompat-v7-24.2.0.jar
>        Required by:
>            Invoice:app:unspecified

Comment: I got same problem after update Android. I have upgrade to com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1 to solved this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621941/android-studio-could-not-find-any-version-that-matches-com-android-supportappco)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As the latest version of the support library according to the [support library changelog](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html) is `v7:24.2.1` and not `v7:24.2.0` modify your `build.gradle` to have `v7:24.2.1`:

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I found and changed what you said, it works!

Comment: what is your source? it would be helpful to be able to look up the latest version at any point in time, not just when you wrote this answer.

Comment: @swrobel Updated my answer. Source is: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue tonight after I upgraded Android SDK Tools. I went to the app/build.gradle file. Down to the dependencies section. Two of my dependencies were highlighted stating I should upgrade to a newer version. I updated to version suggested and the error went away. For my situation I used 24.2.1 of the libraries that caused the error.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. after change  **`compileSdkVersion`**  to **24** , update android support repository and change appcompat version, the problem solved.

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading sdk to your needs and if yet that error is showing, maybe you didn't set the version correctly. You can do it like this:
Create a new project. go to gradle file,

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha2'
```

Maybe you need to change these also so compare them too.

```
minSdkVersion 
targetSdkVersion
```