# Running my Android App on my Alcatel pixi theatre 4 (6) phone

Tags: android, android-studio, google-developers-console

I have issues with running my developed app on my phone from android studio. It is really giving me a lot of concern.
This is error I keep getting.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
```

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+.
>        Versions that do not match:
>            24.0.0-beta1
>            24.0.0-alpha2
>            24.0.0-alpha1
>            23.4.0
>            23.3.0
>            + 18 more
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
>            file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
>            file:/C:/Users/Goodness/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
>            file:/C:/Users/Goodness/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
>            file:/C:/Users/Goodness/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
>        Required by:
>            Testing:app:unspecified
>   Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:design:25.+.
>        Versions that do not match:
>            24.0.0-beta1
>            24.0.0-alpha2
>            24.0.0-alpha1
>            23.4.0
>            23.3.0
>            + 8 more
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/design/maven-metadata.xml
>            file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/design/
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/maven-metadata.xml
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/
>            file:/C:/Users/Goodness/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/maven-metadata.xml
>            file:/C:/Users/Goodness/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/design/maven-metadata.xml
>            file:/C:/Users/Goodness/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/design/
>        Required by:
>            Testing:app:unspecified
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 1 mins 32.229 secs
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Please help me

Comment: 1.) Did you install the Android Support Repository?
-->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621941/android-studio-could-not-find-any-version-that-matches-com-android-supportappco

2.) Looks like a misconfiguration regarding appcompat in your gradle file. Could you please add that file to the question?

Comment: okay I will try it and give you feedback. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Robin . that stopped the error. But I still have one issue. The emulator is not showing my app yet. What do I do?

Comment: Never mind. It works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with the Android Support Repository that wasn't installed. Thanks to @Robin Vinzenz. You can solve the problem checking this link [Android Studio could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621941/android-studio-could-not-find-any-version-that-matches-com-android-supportappco)